# How to decrypt encrypted Travis variables?

Tags: encryption, travis-ci

Travis allows one to encrypt variables in the configuration scripts:

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-encrypted-variables-in-.travis.yml

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys

> (1) If you do not have the travis gem installed, run `gem install travis`.
>
> (2) In your repository directory, run:
>
> `travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add env.matrix`
>
> (3) Commit the changes to your .travis.yml.

After encrypting these variables, how do I find the "identity" of these variables once encrypted? Is this possible?

Let's say several months later I forget what the encrypted variables are---how do I find these out again?